# Send custom response back and capture it on the javascript client using tusdotnet

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, tus, tus-js-client, tusdotnet

I am using `tusdotnet` from `tus.io` in ASP.NET Core Application, I am trying to send back a custom response as I am putting the entries in database and need to send back database `Id` in the response. On the javascript side, after the file successfully gets uploaded, the response is always null.

```
onSuccess: function (response) {
    try {
        console.log(response); // this part is always null. even if the json response was received in the final network call.
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error onSuccess: ', e);
    }                        
}
```

Need to get the response back.

---

https://github.com/tus/tus-js-client/blob/master/docs/api.md

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out, `tusdotnet` by default sends back a response status code as `204 No Content` which means my response was being ignored from the library itself.

I had to change the `HttpContext.Response` from the `Tus` configuration to send status code as `200 OK` in order to pass the response back from the `asp.net core` application. For exapmle in my `OnFileCompleteAsync` event I had to change default status code `(204 No Content)` to `200 OK`:

```
ctx.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK;
await ctx.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new FileUploadResponseModel() { FileName = "Modified File Path", Path = "Extra info regarding the path", FileId = "Database Id" }, ctx.CancellationToken);
```

In order to capture the response in the `onSuccess` callback:

```
onSuccess: function (response) {
    try {
        console.log(response); // This method should have the response after below changes
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error onSuccess: ', e);
    }                        
}
```

I had to modify the `javascript` library in order to properly `emit` the response as the implementation of `204 No Content` was modified to `200 OK`. The function responsible for handling this change was `_emitSuccess`:

```
function _emitSuccess() {
    if (this.options.removeFingerprintOnSuccess) {
        // Remove stored fingerprint and corresponding endpoint. This causes
        // new uploads of the same file to be treated as a different file.
        this._removeFromUrlStorage();
    }
    if (typeof this.options.onSuccess === 'function') {
        this.options.onSuccess();
    }
}
```

Had to modify the above method to:

```
function _emitSuccess(res) {
    if (this.options.removeFingerprintOnSuccess) {
        // Remove stored fingerprint and corresponding endpoint. This causes
        // new uploads of the same file to be treated as a different file.
        this._removeFromUrlStorage();
    }
    if (typeof this.options.onSuccess === 'function') {
        this.options.onSuccess(res);
    }
}
```

After this change has been made, I had to modify all the places where this callback was being executed to pass through the response. Such as in `_handleUploadResponse` callback:

```
this._emitSuccess(res); // pass on the response received in the handler.
```

Similarly, needed to modify all the places it was being consumed.

---

CDN: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tus-js-client@latest/dist/tus.js